# how do I handle redirecting to a login page for fetch requests once they log out or their session expires?

Tags: .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am spinning up a Blazor WASM SPA to replace one of our existing JavaScript based applications, and I am having issues wrapping my head around how to handle expired authentication for the client side of the site.

**Existing setup:**
The existing JavaScript site I am replacing already uses a "server" site (.Net core site with API controllers and cookie based Microsoft Identity logins).  I have middleware in the server site that ensures that on each request coming through, the request is authenticated with a cookie.  If the request is not authenticated, it auto redirects to the login page, like a typical Microsoft Identity based site.

Currently, the JavaScript SPA has logic in it on the front end to ping a special API end point once every 30 seconds to ensure the user is still logged in.  If they are no longer logged in, a specific response is returned to the browser and the code redirects to the login page.

**New setup:**
I know that the WASM/Razor components and their logic are already downloaded to the client when they hit the site, just like .js files would for my current JavaScript SPA, so they can continue using the application even if their session expires or they log out in another tab.  The site's fetch requests will start to fail though if they try to continue using the application and requesting data from the server.  Anything not using fetches and cached local data will continue working, but any new fetch request will fail and then try to redirect to the login page.  This results in the fetch requests returning a redirect, but it is expecting JSON, so it errors out when trying to deserialize a redirect response.

What is the normal way to handle this?  I could set up a similar "heartbeat" style ping to auto-forward them to the login if they are logged out, but that seems hacky to me.  If they navigate to a new "page" component, .Net will handle the redirect, but since this is an SPA, they won't be navigating between pages.

I really just want to be sure if a client's session expires, or they log out, that the Blazor WASM site redirects them to a login page and doesn't just sit there in an unusable state until they refresh, and then they see the login.

Comment: Im not sure how your authentication server looks like, but you could try to identity api calls via the request url in the headers and return a 401 from there instead of continuing to the redirection. Then from your SPA you can implement response interceptors to intercept 401 responses to redirect the user back to the login page via javascript